# How would I convert spark scala dataframe column to datetime?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Say I have a dataframe with two columns, both that need to be converted to datetime format. However, the current formatting of the columns varies from row to row, and when I apply to to_date method, I get all nulls returned.

Here's a screenshot of the format....

[image]

the code I tried is...

```
date_subset.select(col("InsertDate"),to_date(col("InsertDate")).as("to_date")).show()
```

which returned

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your datetime is not in the default format, so you should give the format.

```
to_date(col("InsertDate"), "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm")
```

I don't know which one is month and date, but you can do that in this way.